# progress bar no actualiza

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo un problema al momento de actualizar el `progress bar`. El que uso es de **bootstrap** y tengo la función que realiza el cambio del porcentaje, funciona excelente, pero a la hora de ejecutarla dentro del bucle donde debe realizar la actualización real, no funciona.

Este bucle toma datos de un **json** (que a su vez lo traigo de una consulta mysql) y los imprime en una tabla, el `progress bar` debe actualizarse allí, pero toda esa función me devuelve los resultados una vez termina el proceso y el progress nunca se actualiza. No se si será el contexto donde ejecuto la funcion del progress, pero si no es allí, no se donde mas llamarla, tambien, una vez que se muestran los datos, el progress desaparece, deberia seguir en pantalla y en 0 por si el usuario desea realizar una nueva consulta.

Dejo el codigo:

```javascript
function table(franquicia_seleccionado){
    progress_bar(30); //en esta parte del codigo, si funciona
    const postData={
        from :$('#from').val(),
        to: $('#to').val(),
        franquicia : franquicia_seleccionado,
    }
   
    $.post('model_venta_evolutiva/get_ventas_evolutivas.php', postData).then(response =>{
        progress_bar(30); //en esta parte del codigo, NO funciona
        
        let data = JSON.parse(response);
       
        let template=``;
        let template_total =``;
 
        let total_actual = 0;
        let total_last_month = 0;
        let total_last_year = 0;

        let total_ticket_actual = 0;
        let total_ticket_last_month = 0;
        let total_ticket_last_year = 0;

        

        data.forEach(dato => {
            
           
            let prom = dato.total/dato.tickets;
            let prom_last_month = dato.total_mes_anterior/dato.tickets_mes_anterior;
            let prom_last_year = dato.total_año_pasado/dato.tickets_año_pasado;
            template +=`
                <tr>
                    <td>${dato.local_name}</td>
                    <td>$${number_format(dato.total,2)}</td>
                    <td>$${number_format(dato.total_mes_anterior,2)}</td>
                    <td>$${number_format(dato.total_año_pasado,2)}</td>

                    <td>${number_format(dato.tickets,0)}</td>
                    <td>${number_format(dato.tickets_mes_anterior,0)}</td>
                    <td>${number_format(dato.tickets_año_pasado,0)}</td>

                    <td>$${number_format(prom,2)}</td>
                    <td>$${number_format(prom_last_month,2)}</td>
                    <td>$${number_format(prom_last_year,2)}</td>
                </tr>
            `;

            total_actual += parseFloat(dato.total);
            total_last_month += parseFloat(dato.total_mes_anterior);
           
            if(dato.total_año_pasado == null){
                total_last_year += 0;
            }else{
                total_last_year += parseFloat(dato.total_año_pasado);
            }

            if(dato.tickets_año_pasado == null){
                total_ticket_last_year += 0;
            }else{
                total_ticket_last_year += parseFloat(dato.tickets_año_pasado);
            }
            
        
            total_ticket_actual =dato.tickets;
            total_ticket_last_month = dato.tickets_mes_anterior;

       

        });
        $('#tb_evolutivas').html(template);
         console.log(total_last_year);
        template_total='
            <tr>
                <td><b>TOTAL<b></td>
                <td><b>$${number_format(total_actual,2)}<b></td>
                <td><b>$${number_format(total_last_month,2)}<b></td>
                <td><b>$${total_last_year}<b></td>

                <td><b>${number_format(total_ticket_actual,0)}<b></td>
                <td><b>${number_format(total_ticket_last_month,0)}<b></td>
                <td><b>${number_format(total_ticket_last_year,0)}<b></td>

                <td><b>$${number_format((total_actual/total_ticket_actual),2)}<b></td>
                <td><b>$${number_format((total_last_month/total_ticket_last_month),2)}<b></td>
                <td><b>$${number_format((total_last_year/total_ticket_last_year),2)}<b></td>

               
            </tr>
        ';
    
        $('#tf_evolutivas').html(template_total); 

     
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function progress_bar(newprogress){
    $('#theprogressbar').attr('aria-valuenow', newprogress).css('width', newprogress+'%');
    console.log('newprogress: '+newprogress);
}
```

Comment: Haz un console.log dentro de progress_bar para saber si es llamada y con que valor... Eso te sacaria de dudas.

Comment: Hola @DiegoAndrés, los valores se imprimen en la consola, pero no durante la ejecución de la función, sino, una vez que termina la misma.